# Logical Operator Icons

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, icons, wpf

I'm building a WPF UI for configuring some complex business rules; each *rule* can have many *conditions*, so I figured I would include a drop-down list of logical operators so that the user could have the flexibility required by the business case.

Basically a *rule* has a *logic* and a *behavior*, and under each *rule*, each *condition* also has a *logic*:

- Rules' *behavior* is one of the following:

  - `RuleConditionsMustPass`: this means a *rule* is said to *pass* when the logical operations of all *conditions* under it evaluate to `true`.
  - `RuleConditionsMustFail`: this means a *rule* is said to *pass* when the logical operations of all *conditions* under it evaluate to `false`.
- Rules' *logic* can be one of the following:

  - `And`: all rules with an "And" logic must pass.
  - `Or`: among all rules with an "Or" logic, at least one must pass.
  - `Xor`: among all rules with an "Xor" logic, only one must pass.
- Similarly, conditions' *logic* works the same way: given a "RuleConditionsMustPass" behavior, the rule will pass if all "And" conditions pass and if among all "Or" conditions at least one passes and among all "Xor" conditions only one passes.

What I'm wondering, is whether the icons I've chosen for each logical operator make any sense from a UX point of view, and if using a TreeView for this rule configuration feature is the best approach:

[image]

Clicking the green "+" button here would add a *condition* under that *rule*; clicking the red "-" button would delete that rule. I realize the ComboBox.ItemTemplate is a bit off here, when I'm done with it I'll make sure all items in the dropdown have the same width, and I won't be using the enum names in the directly in the UI.

Comment: As an aside, I'm also planning to use a red shield-shaped "-" icon instead of the red circle, when the underlying record exists in the database - the shield shape becomes a cue saying "this action will require a confirmation". With that in mind, is it ok to use shield shape green tick /red cross for the "Behavior" dropdown?

Comment: At first I was confused, because "and" is listed twice. Then I saw the first "and" is the current selected value and the second "and" on of the list to choose, but still it's irritating.

Comment: I think your concern has more to do with the width of the dropdown than with the selected value showing up in it. What you're describing is vanilla combobox behavior imho; it would be infuriating to lose your selection whenever you click the control, no?

Comment: I never realised it, but Firefox and Chrome list the current selection two times, while IE 10 only shows it one time, see screenshot: http://imgur.com/2EuZ6cW

Comment: This isn't a web app, it's a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) front-end in a class library... I want my comboboxes consistent with the rest of Windows!

Comment: Why do you needs the icons? How technical are the users of this software?

Comment: They're power users; I don't *need* icons, but the values in that dropdown are enums and I have a converter for every other enum that ends up in a combobox, it's just for consistency... and it's prettier :)

Comment: The icons make no sense, logically speaking.

Comment: Since you have AND, OR and XOR, you should also have NOT and brackets operators to enable real boolean searches. (Unless you want users to use RuleA XOR RuleA to get NOT RuleA and reorder all the terms to make them work without brackets). See this question for details: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/44870/687

Comment: Note that you misinterpreted the definition of the XOR operator. It actually means that an odd (non-even) amount of values are true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icons are alright, but I would consider the terminology in general.

- OR - Same as *"match any of the following rules"*?
- AND - Same as *"match all of the following rules"*?
- XOR - Same as *"match one of the following rules"*? At least if there are only 2 options to pick from... [If there are more than 2 it gets more complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

Maybe it's enough just to have Match all / match one / match any / match none to cover all options, together with the possibility to nest rules.

---

### Example (Itunes Smart Playlists):

[image: Logical operator flow]

Comment: Actually, your explanation for XOR is wrong. XOR = an odd (uneven) number of the following rules (e.g. 1, 3, 5, ...).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it! Updated my answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Personally, I would give novice users an option to use XOR or XNOR, it doesn't usually matter for them if both conditions apply anyway.

Comment: I like this approach - match all/one/any. Nice & simple!

Comment: Great! Another related question covering the same topic: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44870/or-and-representations-for-the-non-technical-user

Comment: What would you think of having "Meets any of several criteria" be available on the "rule" pull-down (the one that shows "Media Kind" above) when "All" rules is selected, and have selecting it yield "Any of the following criteria", with the criteria in question nested underneath, and allowing "All of several criteria" within an "Any"?  Nesting only makes sense when switching between "Any" and "All" conditions, so nesting and the outer-scope rule should suffice.

Answer (score 9):

Use Venn-diagram symbols as icons.

OR = two overlapping circles, both colored in.

AND = two overlapping circles, overlapping area colored in.

XOR = two overlapping circles, all but overlapping area colored in.

...

Example from Google search:
[image]

**Edit:**

A few comments:

1. The icons in the question don't make logical sense, one is a branch icon, another is a merge icon and I am not sure what the third symbolizes. Logical diagrams that do explain the operators are either Venn diagrams which are easy to understand or switch diagrams, which may seem strange to many users.
2. XOR is absolutely NOT a "one of" operator, its a "odd (uneven) number of conditions are true" operator.
3. It doesn't usually matter to simple users if one condition is true or multiple ones.
4. In a rule system, you need to let users define operators such as NOT and () brackets, otherwise users will have to complicate their rules e.g. X XOR X AND Y OR X XOR X AND Z instead of NOT X AND (Y OR Z).

See [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/44870/687) and its answers for a way to visualize this.