# Good way to visualize complex AND/OR query/criteria?

Tags: info-visualisation, visual-design

I'm maintaining a webapp with a feature dubbed the "rule form". It's essentially a complex HTML form that users use to build a "rule" with criteria that can be grouped into AND/OR blocks. When all the criteria are true, things happen that the user wants to happen. Think of it as a static query. Something like:

```
Animal
    Fur Color:
        IS Black
        - OR -
        IS NOT Brown
        - OR -
        IS White
    - AND -
    Weight:
        >= 25 lbs
    - AND -
    Lives:
        INSIDE Houses
        - OR -
        OUTSIDE Caves
    - AND -
    Species:
        IS NOT Cat
        - AND -
        IS NOT Dog
        - AND -
        IS NOT Llama
End Animal
```

Important note: Root criteria (Fur Color, Weight, etc.) are always AND's in this tool. The sub-criteria within one root criterion are all either ORs or ANDs, not mixed.

After a user creates a rule, I'd like to be able to show the user a summary of that rule, which means figuring out an elegant way to visualize the complex criteria above. Any suggestions or links to it done well are welcomed. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The webapp I'm maintaining is on a separate network, so I cannot provide a screenshot of the current HTML form, but it's quite similar to the answer provided by @kerr. Please note that I'm interested in a *viewing* capability only. While I'd love to be able to just load up the form when viewing a rule, there are times when that particular module is not available, which is why I'm having to develop a new "viewer". Thanks.

Comment: You are basically trying to dumb down order of operations. Stahp that. Parenthesis are a universally understandable to represent what you need. If your users find parenthesis truly mind-numbing then I am sure life is difficult for them in other aspects.

Comment: Wholeheartedly disagree. The concept of parentheses to encompass distinct logic is intuitive enough, but don't you think that if there is a better way to visualize the data set, UX designers have a responsibility to do that?

Comment: I've used a [heavily customized treeview](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/46318/36606) to do this in another life. I never saw it used in production (got a job elsewhere before launch), but initial user feedback was good - and the rules I had to be able to support configuration for were mind-numbingly complex (pricing rules for doors/window promotions, e.g. Low-E glass is free if model is XYZ or ABC, and order contains more than 4 windows or God knows what else marketing could come up with) - I feel your pain, my sympathies.

Comment: @MegaMatt I respect your disagreement but currently you are the one with a fruitless headache, not me. Quite honestly though, the indentation style in your question lends itself to good readability. Also, a good chunk of UX design is to adhere to expected norms rather than forcing a person to figure out or get frustrated with custom visualization built by some guy they've never met.

Comment: @MegaMatt, one question - are the criteria within root criteria always of the same operand? What I mean is: fur colour is <a> OR <b> OR <c> (all ORs), species is <A> AND <B> AND <C> (all ANDs). Or are any combinations possible? Does the order matter for you? Please, let me know as I might have a solution for you.

Comment: @Mike, highest level criteria - fur, weight, etc - are always AND. Underneath each root, yes, only one operand is legal. The user chooses either AND or OR, and that operant automatically applies to all. Also, you cannot go deeper in the tree than what I've demonstrated.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Agree with your comments. I've got a rough-draft that closely mirrors my example, and it's looking ok.

Comment: Is "IS NOT Brown" encompassing "IS Black"?

Comment: @liori My example lacks some fidelity right there. Those criteria are OR'd together, so either being true would trigger a true boolean. That includes the color black, and it includes colors others than brown.

Comment: @MegaMatt The problem is that if you have "is NOT brown", that essentially means "any other color than brown", which immediately also includes black and white. If you have only 1 "is NOT" criteria, then this isn't an issue. If you have 2 "is NOT" criteria, then you essentially say "any color", because "is NOT black" OR "is NOT white" means "any other color than black (which includes white)" OR "any  other color than white (which includes black)". Some users might be confused by this, and you may want to add some warnings for this.

Comment: @Nzall, the example provided in the question was for illustrative purposes only. Please disregard any flaws in logic. It was meant only as a means to solicit suggestions on visualizations.

Comment: @MegaMatt If there was a better way to visualize it than parentheses, why aren't we using it in programming languages every day? To the contrary, we sometimes hide logic in methods to *avoid* more messy ways of visualizing it all at once. I think the main reason we don't use simple text query engines (with parentheses) is that we don't want to (or don't feel like we have the budget to) write parsers or natural language interpreters for it.

Comment: @jpmc26: "If there was a better way to visualize it than parentheses, why aren't we using it in programming languages every day?" - because the programming languages most of us use "every day" are textual, not visual. Because there's a trade-off between making logical connections in conditions more obvious and saving screen estate for other things, given that our programs consist of more than boolean expressions. Because target audiences have different requirements, and while parentheses will do and be accepted by programmers, other user groups may not be as accepting.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper And yet they're the standard for this kind of logic in every major search engine, which tells me that attempts at making it more graphical weren't successful. Also, our programming languages being textual doesn't exclude usage of newlines and whitespace to achieve more complex effects similar to what you could achieve with a graphical environment. Yet we don't bother. Why? Because it's too complex and doesn't actually help very much. Arbitrarily nested Boolean expressions are hard to decipher no matter how you present them.

Comment: @jpmc26: "which tells me that attempts at making it more graphical weren't successful" - that sounds interesting, do you have any links to concrete attempts of integrating visual queries into any major search engine? Also, are queries with nested conjunctions and disjunctions frequent enough among all search queries in such major search engines to warrant the (considerable!) additional effort to implement an interactive visualization compared to parsing a text string with nested pairs of brackets? "similar to what you could achieve with a graphical environment" - I disagree. Visualization ...

Comment: ... goes a lot further than just spacing and indenting text in different ways. "Yet we don't bother. Why?" - as I already wrote above: Different target audiences, and a trade-off with other factors such as available screen space that are more important when displaying program logic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't have any links to such attempts. Do you have any data suggesting that searching becomes easier with a more complex interface? Google, easily the most successful search engine, uses a pure text search entry form. This form allows special structures for exact searches, Boolean logic, and other [advanced filters](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en). It even has a calculator built in. But they chose to leave it all text based. Google certainly does plenty of research on what gets people to their site (and by extension, what makes searching easier).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The bottom line being if it's such a great way of presenting the info, why isn't it more pervasive in the tools that would most benefit from it and have to appeal to the widest audience?

Comment: @jpmc26: "Do you have any data suggesting that searching becomes easier with a more complex interface?" - comparative evaluations of query visualization approaches such as the one on [Filter/Flow](http://search.proquest.com/openview/fb79e547107bd6a08f1415e436156123/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=1818555) are usually promising when it comes to correctly interpreting Boolean logic. Note, though, that your wording of "a more complex interface" is misleading, as it implies the graphical interface is more complicated for the user. That is not necessarily the case, even though implementation ...

Comment: ... *is* probably more complicated for the developer. "Google, easily the most successful search engine" - for the particular use case of quickly running one-time queries on large amounts of unstructured documents from a website. "what gets people to their site (and by extension, what makes searching easier)" - I hope you are aware these two factors can be aligned, but can also contradict each other. Finally, without any data about what percentage of Google queries is complex enough to feature nested conjunctions and disjunctions, it is not clear to me that Google (or similar search ...

Comment: ... engines) are indeed "the tools that would most benefit from [visual querying approaches]", as you claim. Therefore, their representativeness for the issue at hand is questionable.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I really like the iTunes way of laying out a rule builder. It's quite easy to follow.

With that in mind, here is an example using that paradigm:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVmrRb.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You can see there's an added accelerator in the Fur color & Species options - selecting multiple values of the same type could be displayed as tags which reduces the UI needed. You'll have to see whether this works for you though.

I've found that if you make the language as natural as possible and make it read from left to right, it's much easier to grasp. So instead of using mathematical symbols, add text as well (or in place of). If it reads naturally enough in the query itself, there's no need to have an additional "summary" of the rule.

Comment: +1 This is similar to what Microsoft Excel uses to set conditional logic for cell formatting.

Comment: This doesn't let you `OR` a particular Fur color and Species though? e.g. (If Fur Color is Black and Species is Wolf OR Fur Color is White and Species is Tiger)

Comment: @Ian The OP explicitly says that the root criteria are always ANDed.

Comment: @yo' Oops - skim reading fail!

Comment: +1 for collapsing similar criteria; in the original it's not immediately that there's a NOT before BROWN, even though it changes *everything*. Clearly separating the IN and the NOT IN makes things much clearer.

Comment: Quickbase uses this format, and it works great imo.

Answer (score 38):

How about building a flowchart?

An OR could be expressed by a fork in the flow. An AND could be expressed by joining two criteria in the same flow path.

For example, `( A ∧ B ) ∨ ( C ∧ D )` could be expressed as:

```
( START )
    │
 ┌──┴──┐
 │     │
[A]   [C]
 │     │
[B]   [D]
 │     │
 └──┬──┘
    │
 ( END )
```

Of course, building a web interface that allows you to create such a flowchart would take some time, but it would be graphically clear as a visualization, IMHO.

Comment: +1. Since this will be used for filtering, it may be worth replacing `END` with `include in results` and as a 3rd option next to `A` and `C`, have `everything else` which will connect to `don't include` next to the other end condition

Comment: @Locoluis Thanks. Very creative solution, but as you said, difficult to put together quickly in a web interface. With more screen real estate, more time, and some money to purchase a good JS library for making flowcharts, I see this being a viable option.

Comment: @MegaMatt I've used JointJS before and found it very useful for putting flowcharts together and it has a free version.

Comment: That technique was popularized by [Ben Shneiderman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Shneiderman) as *filter/flow*. As a bonus, the thickness of the flows can be varied along the way to imply the size of the result set after each criterion.

Answer (score 12):

With all the information I'd present something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHd426.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The idea is that OR criteria are placed parallel (one above the other, so the matching animals can pass through any of the criterium) while the AND criteria are placed in series (one next to the other, so the matching animals must pass all of them).

You can play with the graphics here, drawing some sort of paths (with animal tracks) to make the diagram even more visual.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of break something complex down into smaller and more manageable steps. It is always a trade-off between simplicity and efficiency (for power users), and this is something that needs to be considered in the solution.

Comment: @Mike This looks the best so far to me personally, out of all the solutions. I especially like how you can follow the flow through from left to right, and how it implements both text and visual aids.

Comment: Thank you, @Feathercrown. I just came up with an idea, that the arrows can be replaced with a path (like a paved path or such) and the logic gates fields with gates (like fence gates or such). But this should be drawn with taste so it doesn't look childish.

Comment: @Mike Good idea.

Answer (score 6):

How about nested boxes where rules at the same level are arranged in *groups*, such as shown [here](http://querybuilder.js.org/) ?

[image: Demo of querybuilder library showing some rules arranged in a nested order]

[Another version](https://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/):

[image: Demo of querybuilder library showing some rules arranged in a nested order]

Comment: I find that's a fair compromise between ease of implementation and ease of use - I'd make it clearer which of AND|OR is enabled/disabled though; it's not immediately clear from the blue colors which means what. Dark blue = disabled, bright green = enabled would be much less ambiguous IMO.

Comment: I agree. See the newly added version.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, I had encountered a similar issue with a "Rule form".
Looking for different solutions, this seemed to be a valid solution to the problem.

As you see is an If-Then statement, with AND or OR step in between.
All the If-Then statements are connected with AND criteria:

[image: Rule form]

Comment: It might just be personal preference, but I find this suggested form very noisy and not very intuitive. There is no clear meaning what the line connecting the 2nd and 3rd row is doing. The readability is also poor because of the numerous colors, borders, shades, and controls.

Comment: I dont like this at all because the lines almost tell me that the condition doesnt need to satisfy for it to continue.

Comment: @JonH this is an interesting point that you have made, and I wonder if it is something that needs to be considered or not relevant for this use case.

Comment: @LeviJ I agree, minus the part about the colors.

Comment: @LeviJ These are very good suggestions for improvements! Thanks!

Comment: @JonH the lines were used for another reason actually. They were used to symbolize priority of condition, which is my system it was important. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 3):

Let me provide a glimpse of what such a UI looks like in the Views module of the [Drupal](https://drupal.org/) CMS.

[image: Drupal Views and/or UI]

You see filters that are applied to a "view", ie. a dynamically generated list of content items. (The combination of filters doesn't make any sense in this example, I just randomly chose some.) There is another part in the UI for choosing and configuring filters.

On the top level there are "Filter groups", which contain one or more filters. There is a selector for and/or both within the group and between the groups. You can add additional groups if you like.

One thing I like about this UI, is that you can easily drag-and-drop filters between groups.

Answer (score 2):

I really like how Salesforce Marketing Cloud solves this problem:

[image]

You can clearly see what blocks interact with each other and how deep the logic behind filters really is.

Comment: I don't like that this design seems to hide how the conditions are combined together (i.e. ANDs and ORs have background that doesn't contrast and are located in the last place you will look: all the way to the right).